# connect to mongodb remotely

Tags: macos, mongodb, server

I'm just starting with mongoldb (Installed today!).
I installed mongoldb on my ubuntu laptop (already acting as a mySQL server).
I want to be able to work with the mongodb database remotely from my mac.
What do I need to do?
Do I need to install mongodb on my mac as well?

Comment: No you don't. Just open port 27017 (default port) on ubuntu laptop and connect using a client or your application to that

Comment: How do i open the port on the ubuntu laptop (again, very new...)